# File name substring with precedence constraint - SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am using an expression based constraint via an SQL task to determine whether my For Each File loop adds flat files to my database object or not. This is based upon the value of the first character of the flat file name. Steps taken so far:

Added an Execute SQL task with the expression `SubString = SUBSTRING(@[User::FileFound], 1, 1)`.

Set Result Set to `SingleRow`. The ResultSet I have set with a Result Name of `SubString` and a variable name of `User::SubString`.

Then for my Precedence Constraint I have used an expression of `@[User::SubString] = "9"` which validated successfully using the 'Test' button.

However I get the following error text printed to screen:

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "SubString = SUBSTRING(@[User::FileFound], 1, 1)" failed with the following error: "Incorrect syntax near '='.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

My variable FileFound is a string that contains the flat file names being parsed in a loop and SubString is a Boolean. I tried setting Substring up as a string variable, but received the following error message:

```
TITLE: Package Validation Error
------------------------------

Package Validation Error

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error at Foreach Loop Container: The expression "@[User::SubString] = "9"" must evaluate to True or False. Change the expression to evaluate to a Boolean value.

Error at Foreach Loop Container: There was an error in the precedence constraint between "Execute SQL Task" and "Data Flow Task".

 (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Feels like I am on the right track now, but just missing something.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain at a higher level what you are attempting to do?

Comment: set up a constraint on my loop that a flat file will only be added to my DB object when looping if the first character of the file name equals "9".

Comment: very unclear question

Comment: Please try to pass @SubString = SUBSTRING(@[User::FileFound], 1, 1) -- added @ to the parameter. Also you can change SUBSTRING to LEFT(@variable,1).

Comment: this causes the error: '[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "@SubString = SUBSTRING to LEFT(@FileFound,1) " failed with the following error: "Must declare the scalar variable "@SubString".". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that appear wrong.

For your precedent constraint

> The expression "@[User::SubString] = "9"" must evaluate to True or False

You are attempting to use the assignment operator, `=` not test for equality `==`

In your Execute SQL Task, you indicate you have this fragment

```
SubString = SUBSTRING(@[User::FileFound], 1, 1)
```

One, you can't mix stuff like that. If you have a query, it generally needs to be a query that would run against the target database. The exception to that rule is for parameters which is what I *think* you're trying to do.

To fix the query, you'd need to use the appropriate parameterization type for your provider (OLE = `?`, ADO = `@Param`, ODBC = `?`) so it becomes something like

```
SubString = SUBSTRING('?', 1, 1)
```

but that would not be how a native SSIS person would accomplish the root task of identifying the leading character of a variable.

### Do over

You have a Variable called `FileFound` which contains the file name and you have a variable called `SubString` that you want to hold the first character of `FileFound`.

I would skip using the Execute SQL Task and instead, do the work within our Variable `SubString`

For 2005/2008, right click on the Variable and select Properties. Find two properties: `EvaluateAsExpression` and set that to True and for `Expression` set that as `SUBSTRING(@[User::FileFound], 1, 1)`  Notice we don't provide an explicit assignment in the form A = B. Instead, we are setting the property on our variable to be the result of evaluating the operation. The beautiful thing about this approach is that every time you go to access the Variable, it will evaluate itself and you have the correct value. With your approach, you'd need to keep running that task and possibly copy and pasting it whenever you need it.

For 2012+, they simplified the clickpath for setting expressions. All you have to do is put the expression in the Expression box in the Variable's window and the EvaluateAsExpression is automatically set.

Finally, creating Variables costs you nothing for performance. You can inspect the value of a variable at any point within the execution of an SSIS package. You can print them to the screen, log to file, whatever you want. What you can't do is look at the value of an expression that exists on an object (a task, a precedent constraint, etc). If your logic for the precedent constraint is acting funny - how do you look and see what the value is at the point of execution? You can't.

But if you create a third Variable, `ProcessFile` make it of type Boolean and then use the expression `@[User::SubString] == "9"` on it, look at what happens. You can set a break point and ensure your logic is correct, you can emit that value for any processing log and when the logic changes (because we need the 9 and 7 files to go), you make a change in one place and all the places that are keyed on the value of our new variable "just work."

### Putting it all together

[image]

Option 1

Inside your foreach enumerator you need a parent task to be able to add a precedent constraint to the task that actually does work. Here I used a Sequence Container as it costs nothing to use and by naming it as such, it's purpose is apparent. Since ProcessFile is boolean, I used the shorthand notation of `@[User::ProcessFile]` as my expression. No need to write `@[User::ProcessFile] == true`

Option 2

Since you never specified what you were trying to do from a big picture perspective, you might be able to adjust your Foreach Loop Container to just look for all the 9*.* files. then you don't need either the SubString or ProcessFile variables. The only thing the enumerator will pick up will be the files that begin with 9

Foreach File Enumerator. In the *Files* section, you specify what you'd like to load. Here I specify `9*.txt` which will find all files that begin with 9 and end with a .txt extension

[image]

Comment: thanks for replying. where do i then plug in the condition @[User::ProcessFile] == TRUE into my loop? which component should that become an expression for?

Comment: i am trying to run a loop that only loads flat files in a directory that begin with a 9 into a DB object. inside my for each loop i have a dataflow object and inside that a flat file source connected to a DB destination. for option 2, within the for each editor im assuming i would add an expression within the expressions tab, but i am unsure which property option i should chose. am i looking along the correct lines? thanks

Comment: @gdogg371 It's even easier than that, make your FELC editor look like the above

Comment: of course! how stupid of me...oh well it's been a good learning curve...im going to try using 9* in the filepath wildcard now...just to note though, when i dragged a sequence container into my for each file loop, connected that to my data flow object and edited the green line to have an expression of the code ran without errors and a DB object was created, but nothing was loaded into it...

Answer (score 1):

If i do understand you correctly what you want to achive is to start a loop based on some condition which comes from a previous ExecuteSQLTask. 
So does it boil down to something like this:
[image]

If so then here is what I did:

a) Get the ResultSet into a variable
[image]

b) Use the Variable and evaluate if it is 9 or not
[image]

**Note:** you need to specify two(!)= signs. Then the expression evaluates to true or false ( see your error above where it complains about this)

For demonstrations I have created two flows  to show what happens when the condition matches and one when it not matches.

 Note: I did not configure the Foreach Loop Container.That is why the Data Flow Task is not green. It was never called.
[image]